# Bash: returning line numbers from a function

Tags: bash, function, error-handling, line-numbers

I am trying to implement an abort function in a bash script, currently it looks like this:

```
function abort {
  LOGFILE=/var/log/bash_test
  DATE=$(date "+%Y %b %a %H:%M:%S")
  printf "\n------| ERROR: %s line %03d in %s |------\n" "$DATE" "$2" "${0}" >> "$LOGFILE"
  echo "$1" >> "$LOGFILE"
}

abort "Some kind of error..." $LINENO
```

This will produce this in /var/log/bash_test

```
------| ERROR: 2014 Jan Tue 12:50:12 line 007 in /home/user/test.sh |------
Some kind of error
```

My question is this: The method of giving the line number manually (eg. $2 < $LINENO) is ugly and repetitive. Is there a way to make this function detect the $LINENO from outside the function automatically? So that i can give the command

```
abort "Some kind of error..."
```

And still get the line number?

Comment: Please don't put "[SOLVED]" in your title. We already have plenty of UI elements that we use for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use BASH_LINENO:

```
$ cat test.sh 
my_environment() {
    echo "Stack size: ${#BASH_LINENO[@]}"
    echo "Caller line: ${BASH_LINENO[$((${#BASH_LINENO[@]} - 2))]}"
}
my_environment
$ sh test.sh 
Stack size: 2
Caller line: 5
```

That is, the second to last entry will be the line number where the call to `my_environment` happened.

From the `man bash` section about `BASH_LINENO`:

> An array variable whose members are the line numbers in source  files  where  each  corresponding member  of  FUNCNAME  was  invoked.   ${BASH_LINENO[$i]}  is  the  line number in the source file (${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}) where ${FUNCNAME[$i]} was called (or  ${BASH_LINENO[$i-1]}  if  referenced within another shell function).  Use LINENO to obtain the current line number.

Answer (score 0):

with awk, you can get the line number. Below command will search the key word "ERROR" first, and export the line number.

```
awk '/ERROR/{print NR}' logfile
```

Comment: Hm.. interesting solution, but it will not work in my case. I have several abort calls in my script. running awk '/abort/{print NR}' logfile will print all the abort statements in my code, but not the abort statement that was actually executed.

Comment: @BMW It doesn't do what OP wanted.